# Creating JSON without the use of any external library?

Tags: javascript, json

SORRY! EDIT ON OLD BROWSERS prior to ie8!
In order to create XML on the fly in JS, one can do the below,
Is there any way I can achieve the same - creating JSON on the fly in JS without the use of any external library?

```js
    var parent  =  document.createElement("parent");
    var children = document.createElement('children');
    var child1 =   document.createElement('child1');
    var child2 =   document.createElement('child2');
    
    var textNode1 = document.createTextNode("some text1");
    var textNode2 = document.createTextNode("some text2");
    
    child1.appendChild(textNode1 );
    child2.appendChild(textNode2 );
    
    children.appendChild(child1);
    children.appendChild(child2);
    
    parent.appendChild(children);
    alert(parent.outerHTML);
```

Comment: or `JSON.stringify` @Borjante

Comment: @Borjante — "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Comment: Oh, yes, it's friday afternoon you know :P

JSON.stringify is what you look for

Comment: @Quentin, yes I messed up and wrote out the wrong one

Comment: sorry, the question was referring old IE Versions, should i delete it and repost?

Answer (score 0):

Just use JSON.stringify()
i.e.

```
var o={a:12};
JSON.stringify(o);
```

results in

```
"{"a":12}"
```